# Reverse for 'post' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 8}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['Loader/post/$'] "DANGO"

Tags: python, django

urls.py

```
app_name = 'Loader'

urlpatterns = [
    path('post_detail/', views.Loader_post_view.as_view(), name="post_detail"),
    path('post/', views.post.as_view(), name="post"),
    path('my_job/', views.Loader_post_list.as_view(), name="my_job"),
    path('delete/<int:pk>', views.Loader_post_delete.as_view(), name="Delete"),
    path('update/<int:pk>', views.Loader_post_update.as_view(template_name="post_detail.html"), 
    name="Update")
]
```

this is my models.py

```
class Loader_post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="Loader")
    pick_up_station = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    destination_station = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    sender_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    receiver_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    sending_item = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    #image_of_load = models.ImageField(default='',upload_to='static/img')
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    metric_unit = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    pick_up_time = models.DateField()
    drop_time = models.DateField()
    paid_by = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    published_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)


def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("Loader:post", kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

this if my views.py

```
class Loader_post_view(CreateView,LoginRequiredMixin):

    form_class = forms.Loader_post_form
    model = Loader_post
    template_name = "post_detail.html"



def form_valid(self, form):
    print(form.cleaned_data)
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.user = self.request.user
    self.object.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

this is my post form in html

```
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-row">

        <div class="col">{% render_field form.pick_up_station class="form-control" placeholder="Enter pick_up_station"%}</div>
        <div class="col">{% render_field form.destination_station class="form-control" placeholder="Enter destination_station"%}</div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col">{% render_field form.sender_name class="form-control" placeholder="Enter sender_name"%}</div>
        <div class="col">{% render_field form.phone_number class="form-control" placeholder="Enter phone_number"%}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col">{% render_field form.receiver_name class="form-control" placeholder="Enter receiver name"%}</div>
        <div class="col">{% render_field form.sending_item class="form-control" placeholder="Enter sending_item"%}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col">{% render_field form.weight class="form-control" placeholder="Enter weight"%}</div>
        <div class="col">{% render_field form.metric_unit class="form-control" placeholder="Enter metric_unit"%}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col">{% render_field form.quantity class="form-control" placeholder="Enter quantity"%}</div>
        <div class="col">{% render_field form.pick_up_time class="form-control" placeholder="Enter pick_up_time"%}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col">{% render_field form.drop_time class="form-control" placeholder="Enter drop_time"%}</div>
        <div class="col">{% render_field form.paid_by class="form-control" placeholder="Enter paid_by"%}</div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-full" type="submit">submit</button>
</div>
```

now my question is when i click on submit it shows that error and sometime when i put **'post'** by replacing self it will work fine **'pk':self.pk** however, if new user logged in and try to post the data it will not store onto the database please help me to find out this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `post` url has no `pk` url parameter. You need to add one:

```
app_name = 'Loader'

urlpatterns = [
    path('post_detail/', views.Loader_post_view.as_view(), name="post_detail"),
    path('post/<int:pk>', views.post.as_view(), name="post"),
    path('my_job/', views.Loader_post_list.as_view(), name="my_job"),
    path('delete/<int:pk>', views.Loader_post_delete.as_view(), name="Delete"),
    path('update/<int:pk>', views.Loader_post_update.as_view(template_name="post_detail.html"), 
    name="Update")
]
```

Comment: when i do that it shows this error.........Reverse for 'post' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['Loader/post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']

Comment: @dilmeetpadda: yes, that is because you have a pattern somwhere in your code like `{% url 'Loader:post' %}`, or `reverse('post')`, but that does not make any sense if you want to show a *single* `Post` object in that view.